# Set a string to a value in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a line of code where I'm trying to get the value (the type is marked as general on excel) in a certain cell.  I wrote:

```
Dim answer as String
answer = Range(Cells(CellA.Row, CellB.Column)).Value
```

I know that CellA and CellB are not the problem, because I use them in other parts of my code.  I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `Range`, because you are just accessing the single cell:

```
Dim answer as String
answer = Cells(CellA.Row, CellB.Column).Value
```